# Verificar se um processo não está rodando para então executá-lo

Tags: linux, bash

Preciso rodar um determinado comando via terminal. Porém esse comando só deverá ser rodado se o processo do mesmo não estiver rodando. Se ele estiver rodando, não é necessário fazer nenhuma outra operação.

Como fazer isso no linux?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Existem várias maneiras de fazer isso. Uma delas é utilizando o `pgrep`:

```
pgrep gedit
```

Se o gedit estiver rodando, um número será retornado.

```
17805
```

Esse número é o ID do processo (PID). Esse número obviamente muda.

Combinando isso em um *Shell Script*:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Verifica se o gedit está sendo executado
if pgrep "gedit" > /dev/null
then
    echo "Executando"
else
    echo "Parado"
fi
```

Retirado de [How to determine whether a process is running or not and make use it to make a conditional shell script?](https://askubuntu.com/a/157787)

**Nota importante:**

Para garantir que a pesquisa seja pelo nome exato do processo, utilize a opção -x, exemplo:

```
pgrep ged
```

Retornaria qualquer processo que tenha `ged` no nome.

Por sua vez:

```
pgrep -x gedit
```

Retornaria apenas os processos que sejam exatamente `gedit`.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode criar um shell script que retorne quantos processos estão rodando. É claro que o else pode ser suprimido.

```
#!/bin/sh
# Verificacao se servico esta online

qtde=$(ps aux | grep "mysqld" | wc -l)

if test "$qtde" = "1"
then
  echo "MySQL is offline";
  echo "Starting...";
  /etc/init.d/mysql stop;
  /etc/init.d/mysql start;
else
  echo "MySQLd is online." ;
  echo "Nothing to do.";
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Iniciando um processo uma única vez, ao abrir uma sessão no terminal. Coloque no final do arquivo ~/.bashrc:

```
pid=$(pgrep -x redshift)

if [ "$pid" = "" ]
then
  redshift &
fi
```